# start mysql service if it is down programatically

Tags: mysql, cron, monitoring

I have a ubuntu server and i want to monitor it and start mysql service if it goes down, what can i do programatically to implement this.

I see this solution and set it via cron to execute every minute.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" =~ "start/running" ]]
then
    /usr/sbin/service mysql start
fi
```

**but would setting a cron to execute every minute load my server.**

Any help in this direction will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, running a short script like that every minute won't stress your server.  So programmatically, assuming you tested it and all, I don't see much wrong with your approach.

I'd be more concerned as to why your service randomly shuts down though, have you looked for clues in logs?  Depending on the severity of the cause, perhaps implementing a monitoring tool like nagios or icinga might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its getting shut down because load on the server, we are planning to move to a better server and needed a temporary fix till we move. Thanks again.